# Unsuccessful content negotation with excel file

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, content-negotiation, media-type

I have a Spring Boot application with an already working endpoint that produces an xlsx file.
Now, I want to implement content negotation on this endpoint but I always receive `406 Not Acceptable`.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-03-09T18:44:56.997+0000",
    "status": 406,
    "error": "Not Acceptable",
    "message": "Could not find acceptable representation",
    "path": "/students/excel"
}
```

And I am using URL parameters and I am calling it like that

```
localhost:8080/students/excel/excel?format=xlsx
```

The implementation

Endpoint

```
    @PostMapping(path = "/excel", produces = {"application/vnd.ms-excel"})
    public byte[] generateExcel(HttpServletResponse response, final @RequestBody @NonNull Criteria criteria) {
            
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");

        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Students.xlsx");

        return studentService.generateExcelReport(response, criteria);
    }
```

The method that is finalizing the excel file.

```
   public static byte[] write(HttpServletResponse response, final @NonNull XSSFWorkbook workbook) {
        
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            os.writeTo(response.getOutputStream());
            workbook.write(os);
            workbook.close();
            return os.toByteArray();
        } catch (final IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error generating excel", ex);
        }
    }
```

And the relevant method on `WebConfiguration` that implements `WebMvcConfigurer`

```
    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {

        configurer.favorPathExtension(false).
                        favorParameter(true).
                        parameterName("format").
                        ignoreAcceptHeader(true).
                        useJaf(false).
                defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
                mediaType("xlsx", MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    }
```

I tried a lot of combinations with `MediaType` and on `WebConfiguration` and the attribute of `produces` like
`application/csv` to check if there is a possibility that it could work due to formating of the excel file and others. But I couldn't overcome this status. When setting it to `application/json` and `text/plain` it works but it's not the wanted functionality or the correct one.

When I am not using content negotiation, the generation of the excel works as I mentioned.

Edit:
Based on suggestions, I changed the content type to `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` and changed the header of both `Accept` and `Content-Type` on Postman and still receive `406`.

This is how the request on Postman looks
[image]

I also debugged the application and it doesn't enter the method of the endpoint, it seems to fail instantly because of the produces value.

Ι want to add that this is a POST request that accepts a JSON. So, using any other content-type on Postman will break it.

**Update**

It works by using the accept header instead of parameters and changing `WebConfigurer` method. But, I wanted to to use URL parameters and to understand why they don't work.

```
@Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(true).
                favorParameter(false).
                ignoreAcceptHeader(false).
                useJaf(false);
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to set the `Accept` header to `application/vnd.ms-excel` in your call.

Comment: Content-type for xslx is `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

Comment: I tried implementing both of your suggestions. @Jens I forgot to mention that was the first Content-Type I've used and read that is the prefered one now `application/vnd.ms-excel` maybe I was wrong on that, I tried it again with the suggestion of  @Seelenvirtuose and sadly I still receive 406. I will update the question with the tests. I am worried also about `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA`, I am not sure about that at all.

Comment: Have you changed both the string in produces and in set cntenttype?

Comment: @Jens Yes I have on both.

Comment: I also want to add that it doesn't even enter the method of the endpoint. It fails instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in order to make it work with URL parameters, as it was my first intention.
I added a new Media Type of `vnd.ms-excel` on `WebConfiguration` as following.

```
    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(false).
                        favorParameter(true).
                        parameterName("format").
                        ignoreAcceptHeader(true).
                        useJaf(false).
                defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
                mediaType("xlsx", new MediaType("application","vnd.ms-excel"));
    }
```

On `Accept` header of the request I added the value `application/vnd.ms-excel`.

Finally, by calling the excel endpoint now with the needed format it generates the excel file properly.

```
localhost:8080/students/excel/excel?format=xlsx
```